# PhpMailer: SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to use the PhpMailer on a managed server (I only have access via cPanel), and I'm getting this error:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT:
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO stefanomenci.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved
 [...]
SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved
```

This is the script:

```
require ("/path/to/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mydomain.com";
$mail->Port = 2096;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "name@mydomain.com";
$mail->Password = "****";
$mail->From = "name@mydomain.com";
$mail->FromName = "Name";
$mail->AddAddress("myaddress@gmail.com");
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "Subject";
$mail->Body = "y<b>a</b>y";
$mail->AltBody = "yay";
$mail->Send();
```

If port is wrong it fails immediately with "failed to connect to the server".

If port is missing it says "Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client, or login to the server before sending your message."

If port is correct it waits 10 seconds and shows the error shown above, regardless of the user name and password being correct or not.

Removing `$mail->IsSMTP()` works, but often the emails go straight to the spam folder.

I found many posts about similar problem with PhpMailer, but they usually use Google instead of mydomain.com and they never have this error message.

Comment: mention your smtp host which is something like mail.mydomain.com instead of mydomain.com in the host

Comment: Is using the port 2096 specified anywhere in the documenten by either your hosting provider or by the destination SMTP server?

Comment: With or without `mail.` returns the same error. With `smtp.` or any other subdomain fails with `SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)
SMTP connect() failed.`

Comment: Accessing the email through cPanel uses `mydomain.com:2096`. I tried using other numbers, but it says `failed to connect to the server`. So I assume is the correct one. How do I check if it is not?

Comment: cpanel port is not your smtp port.. ask your hosting provider for the smtp host address and port.. try using port 465 with mail.mydomain.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use either port 25 or 465 as mentioned above. On port 2096 is running a webserver as we can see in the connection ( SERVER -> CLIENT: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved ).

Comment: I marked this as answer, because the port and domain were wrong. I found the instructions for the mail configuration in cPanel, the domain is mail.mydomain.com and the port is 26. Following the instruction the error in the subject changes (that's why I set this as answer), but it still does not connect with other error messages. I'm still investigating, and I will eventually ask another question with a different subject.