# PHPMailer SMTP Auth Error: could not authenticate

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, smtp-auth

This is my code for my email system in my website based on PHPMailer.
And i have a auth error with SMTP, tried many solutions from stackoverflow, checked and re-checked every detail, password, email.
But can be a simple mistake from my part.

PHPMailer 5.2.13

PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.20

and using my Web Hosting SMTP service

```
include_once("PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$para       = "testTarget@domain";
$nome       = $_POST['nome'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$telefone   = $_POST['telefone'];
$assunto    = $_POST['assunto'];
$msg        = $_POST['msg'];
$mail       = new PHPMailer(true);
$pop        = new POP3();
$msg_final  = "";

//MSG Build
$msg_final .= "Telefone: ".$telefone."\n\n<br />";
$msg_final .= "Assunto: ".$assunto."\n\n<br />";
$msg_final .= "Email: ".$email."\n\n<br /><br />";
$msg_final .= $msg;

try{
    $mail->SetFrom($email, $nome);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email, $nome);

    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->MsgHTML($msg_final);

    $mail->AddAddress($para, "Central Pires");

    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    //Doesnt work anyway
    $pop->Authorise('imap.server', 143, 30, 'no-reply=server', 'pass', 0);

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.hostserver.domain";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; //ssl
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Port = 587; //or 465
    $mail->Username = "no-reply@hostserver.domain";
    $mail->Password = "password";

    $mail->Send();
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I tried update update my PHPMailer, checked OpenSSL is enabled.

Checked server ports and address, i tried login with the no-reply email on server and works normal

Comment: set `$mail->SMTPDebug` to `2` and check the info what's going on.
`$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`

Comment: password command failed.

changed to gmail for now and is working normally, but i am trying to solve this problem with my smtp server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562015/phpmailer-smtp-error-ehlo-command-failed

Comment: Enable debug as @MubinKhalid said and sho us exact error shown there.

Comment: Why are you trying to do POP-before-SMTP on an IMAP port? Why are you trying to do it at all given that you're also doing regular auth over SSL?

Comment: i tried everything Synchro, including some methods from PHPMailer examples, i remove POP, only SMTP but is a error from my server only.
When i found a correct way for this i bring it for the post.

For this time is just a auth problem with the "password command failed"

I only changed to Gmail before i correct this..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working example, maybe helps you:

```
$strTo = array("test@test.com");

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = $email_from;
$email->FromName  = $name;
$email->Subject   = $subject;
$email->Body      = $body;
$email->AddReplyTo($email_from, $name);

foreach($strTo as $receiver){
    $email->AddAddress( $receiver );
}
if(isset($_FILES['fileAttach'])){
    $name_file = $_FILES['fileAttach']['name'];
    $path_file  = $_FILES['fileAttach']['tmp_name'];

    $email->AddAttachment( $path_file ,$name_file );
}

$flgSend = $email->Send();
if($flgSend)  
{
    //success
}else{
    //error
}
```